# Magento 2.4.5-p1: Error on a fresh installation on a VPS: Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

I am getting HTTP ERROR 500 error on the frontend and this error in error logs :

```
[2023-01-27T16:23:35.766286+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property Magento\Framework\Error\Processor::$_errorDir is deprecated in /var/www/html/pub/errors/processor.php on line 171 in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:62
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
private $headersSent;
```

in file

> vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Response.php

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to "wrong" PHP version. Check the PHP requirements of the Magento version and use that one.

I had the same error trying to setup an installtion with PHP 8.2 when it needed 7.4.